# Showing a <section> with URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've THIS site: [Test Site](http://learningdomain.esy.es/example/). I'm trying to get a URL for the "section.more", so I can connect to a URL like http:// ... .es/example/#more and I get loaded automatically on #more.
The problem is that if I try to surround "section.more" with an anchor, I get the URL, but the animation get broken and I can't load directly on the second section by writing its URL in the browser bar.

How can I do this?

Codes:

HTML:

```
<section class="intro">
        CSS style and jQuery scrolling test page
            <a href="#more" id="showmore"></a>
        </section>

        <a href="#more"><section class="more">
            <nav><div id="back">Go Top</div></nav>
            <div id="cont">
                <img alt="" src="" class="left">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque porta at leo sed viverra. Donec gravida nisi massa, sit amet interdum quam laoreet et. Etiam a lorem lectus. Praesent in cursus urna. Proin sollicitudin eget ante vitae sodales. Aliquam luctus vulputate ipsum, nec gravida odio placerat sed. Nunc at metus scelerisque, consectetur tortor et, facilisis ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                <img alt="" src="" class="right">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque porta at leo sed viverra. Donec gravida nisi massa, sit amet interdum quam laoreet et. Etiam a lorem lectus. Praesent in cursus urna. Proin sollicitudin eget ante vitae sodales. Aliquam luctus vulputate ipsum, nec gravida odio placerat sed. Nunc at metus scelerisque, consectetur tortor et, facilisis ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>    
            </div>
        </section></a>
```

CSS

```
.more {
background: #3B383B;
position: absolute;
top:100%; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
display: none;
}

.more nav {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
position: fixed;
top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
height: 50px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
display: none;
z-index: 99;
}

.more #back {
position: fixed;
top: 51px;
background: transparent;
border-left: 3px solid #2083cc;
border-right: 3px solid #2083cc;
border-bottom: 3px solid #2083cc;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
width: 150px;
height: 25px;
padding-top: 3px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Raleway';
font-weight: 200;
left: 46%;
cursor: pointer;
}

.more #cont {
border: 1px solid #000;
position: inherit;
left: 20%; right: 20%;
top: 50px; bottom: 0;
z-index: 1;
padding: 60px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

jQuery for animations:

```
        $("#showmore").on("mouseover", function() {
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
        }).on("mouseout", function() {
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
        }).on("click", function() {
            $(".more").css("display", "inline").animate({ top: 0 }, 1000, function() {
                $(".more nav").fadeIn( 1000 );
            });
        });

        $(".more #back").on("click", function() {
            $(".more").animate({ top: "100%" }, 1000, function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); });
            $(".more nav").fadeOut( 1000 );
        });
```

Comment: Post the code so we can see.

Comment: Here you there: http://jsfiddle.net/Lue65/

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti you should edit your question with the appropriate information (code). While fiddles are great, they won't necessarily be available forever. We don't want SO to rely on outside resources because, well, then it'd be doing just that.

Comment: @Luxelin, should I add all the code I you think is necessary only the HTML and JQuery?

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti Add the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AstroCB I added all the code necessary for the page.
I edited also the main text with right codes. :)

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti Well, if you were only asking for code as a question, it would be off-topic. If you were asking for code *and* providing what you've tried that doesn't work (which you have, making it on-topic), you have a "problem." Your "problem" (may not be the right word) here is `but it seems not working if I call #more in the URL bar`. You only need to include code that is crucial to the question: only include all of the code for the page if all of it contributes to what you're asking about. In this case, including all of the code is probably appropriate.

Comment: @AstroCB, ok. So, I want to put an "anchor" to the section.more, so I can write in the URL bar http:// ... .es/example/#more or something like this and bypass the elements that are inside section.intro.
I tried by putting a name="more" in section.more or surrounding it with < a name="more" > and call it with a < a href="#more" > on the arrow, but it doesn't work. I didin't put the tries because I thought they were useless. This is the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti Ah, I see. Then, yes, including your whole page's code is fine.

Comment: @AstroCB... oh, right... is because I put my right and complete code on the first post... the problem is that I already don't know how to show that as code... I'm now editing the code on the first post.

Comment: @AstroCB edited the main text with codes. Can you understand the problem now? (I don't know if you understand that)